# Cannot build .NET 5 in Jenkins on RHEL8

Tags: .net, jenkins-pipeline, .net-5, rhel8

I am trying to setup a pipeline in Jenkins that should build a .NET 5 Web application. However I am not able to build it due to a missing package. I get the following error:

> error NU1101: Unable to find package
> Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.rhel.8-x64. No packages exist with this id
> in source(s)

I have a custom NuGet source and the standard api.nuget.org. I have searched for the given package but I cannot find it. I have tried to add `--no-self-contained` or `--self-contained false` to the the `dotnet build` command but I get an "unknown switch" error.

Here are some details of the dotnet I have:

> - dotnet --info [Pipeline] echo .NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:   5.0.206  Commit:    0cf287db1b
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     rhel  OS Version:  8  OS Platform:
> Linux  RID:         rhel.8-x64  Base Path:
> /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/5.0.206/
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 5.0.10   Commit:  e1825b4928
>
> .NET SDKs installed:
> 2.1.526 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]
> 3.1.118 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]
> 5.0.206 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]
>
> .NET runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.19
> [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.10
> [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30
> [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.19
> [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.10
> [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

In Jenkins I have just a simple shell command `dotnet build Web.csproj` with given sources.
I need to have my dotnet application build and published in the Jenkins workspace. After that I have to process the artifact but so far I am stuck with the build.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

[EDIT]
The output of `rpm -qa | grep dotnet` is

> - rpm -qa
> - grep dotnet [Pipeline] echo dotnet-targeting-pack-3.1-3.1.19-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-sdk-3.1-3.1.118-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-sdk-5.0-5.0.206-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-host-5.0.10-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-sdk-2.1.5xx-2.1.526-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-apphost-pack-3.1-3.1.19-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-apphost-pack-5.0-5.0.10-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-runtime-2.1-2.1.30-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-hostfxr-3.1-3.1.19-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-templates-3.1-3.1.119-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-hostfxr-5.0-5.0.10-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-templates-5.0-5.0.207-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-host-fxr-2.1-2.1.30-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-targeting-pack-5.0-5.0.10-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-sdk-2.1-2.1.526-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-runtime-3.1-3.1.19-1.el8_4.x86_64
>   dotnet-runtime-5.0-5.0.10-1.el8_4.x86_64

Comment: Try `dotnet bulid -r linux-x64`.

Comment: To help us debug, can you include the output of `rpm -qa | grep dotnet` from the pipeline?

Comment: tried `dotnet build -r rhel.8-x64` but did not work

Comment: What about `dotnet bulid -r linux-x64`?

Comment: I just did the `dotnet build -r linux-x64` but I got something else: error NETSDK1134: Building a solution with a specific RuntimeIdentifier is not supported. If you would like to publish for a single RID, specifiy the RID at the individual project level instead.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you report an issue at https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore/issues/new and we can have a more detailed discussion to try and find out what broke for you. A set of build logs (maybe `dotnet build -v:n`?) would be nice to have too.

Comment: I have found the issue. As usual it is due to the one asking the question. I was running the `dotnet build` on the .sln file which resulted in the behavior I have described earlier. Using `dotnet build` over the correct .csproj file + giving the correct runtime `-r linux-x6` did the job. Thanks for helping!